# Why is it 'speaking'/'speech' instead of 'speeking'/'speech' or 'speaking'/'speach'?

Tags: etymology, american-english, orthography, vowels

Why is it *speaking/speech* instead of *speeking/speech* or *speaking/speach*?

Comment: You *do* realize that English spelling is mostly arbitrary, like Chinese characters, and is not supposed to "make sense". Right?

Comment: Ok, I guess that's the answer then.

Comment: The fact that you have _break_ and _breach_ both spelt with _ea_ confirms how arbitrary it can be.

Comment: Actually, a bunch of English teachers got together back is 1627 and made up a list of words that they would spell oddly, just to drive students crazy.  It's a conspiracy!!

Comment: @John Lawler: neither English spelling nor Chinese spelling has a completely arbitrary relationship to the sounds, and the relationship for English is much more straightforward than for Chinese.

Comment: @Chloe: If you're interested in etymology, a better way of phrasing the question would be to ask "is there a reason for this difference in spelling? If there is, what is it?" Either a "yes" or a "no" answer should provide supporting evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spelling history of *speech* from the OED:

> α. OE–ME spræc, sprec, ME sprace, spræche.
>
> β. OE spæc, spec, ME spece, ME spæche ( spache, spiche), ME–15 speche (ME spieche), ME–15 spech, 15– speech, 15–16 speach, speache; Sc.15 speitche, 15–16 speiche.

The spelling history of *speak* from the OED:

> α. OE sprecan, spreocan, spræcan; north. spreca, spræca, -spreaca; sprecca, spræcca; ME sprecon.
>
> β. OE specan (ME -on), OE–ME specen, ME speken (ME Orm. spekenn), ME spekyn; OE–ME spæcon, ME -en, ME spæ(c)ken; ME speoken.
>
> γ. ME–15 speke, ME–15 spek, ME spec, speck, ME speike, 15–16 speake, 15–17 Sc. speik, 15– speak (Irish 17–18 spake).

Comment: Wow I totally didn't understand that, but looks legit. With so many variations, perhaps someone at some point did spell them similar, but they were not popular enough.

Comment: That just gives more of the difference. Can you elaborate on 'why'?

Comment: @Mitch: whimsy and serendipity.

Answer (score 5):

There actually does seem to be an explanation for the different spellings of *speak* and *speech,* and it even covers why *speech* would have variant spellings with <ea>. The ancestors of these words had different vowels in Proto-Germanic.

The first thing you should know is that Middle English had two phonetic types of "long e": high-mid (this usually corresponds to a modern spelling with <ee>) and low-mid (this usually corresponds to a modern spelling with <ea>).

#### Speak

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speak), the verb *speak* comes from Old English *sprecan*. The loss of the **r** is irregular, but the development of the vowel is regular. The "short e" of Old English was regularly lengthened in some contexts (this is called "open syllable lengthening") resulting in a long low-mid vowel in Middle English, which corresponds as I said to the spelling <ea> in modern English.

#### Speech

Wiktionary says *speech* comes from Old English *sprǣċ*, with a long vowel. The loss of the **r** is irregular, just as in *speak,* but the development of the vowel is actually expected to be variable and to have <ee> as a possible outcome. To explain why, we actually have to go back even further than Old English (at least, Old English in its standardized form).

According to *[Complete Works Of Geoffrey Chaucer](https://books.google.com/books?id=rUR8CgAAQBAJ&pg=PP25&lpg=PP25&dq=The%20use%20of%20y%20and%20i%20letter%20long%20vowel%20in%20chaucer&source=bl&ots=EAg2fAKudk&sig=Kdv07VtnoYOuA3yFx6oYGx8rg1Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFz4WDtYbUAhUl24MKHYU7D4gQ6AEIQjAG#v=onepage&q=before%20we%20can%20shew%20these%20clearly%2C%20it%20is%20necessary%20to%20observe&f=false),* by W.W. Skeat, in Middle English the vowel height of "long e" could be "stable" or "unstable" depending on the source.

- Long e corresponding to Old English (southern/Anglo-Saxon dialect) **ē** was stable and high-mid.
- Long e corresponding to Old English (southern/Anglo-Saxon dialect) **ǣ** was stable and low-mid if it was from Proto-Germanic ***ai** in an umlauting environment.
- Long e corresponding to Old English (southern/Anglo-Saxon dialect) **ǣ** was *unstable,* and could be either high-mid or low-mid in Middle English, if it came from the Proto-Germanic vowel corresponding to Gothic **ē**. (Skeat writes this PG vowel as "ǣ", but the modern convention seems to be to use *ē: Wiktionary gives *sprēkijō.)  Specifically, Skeat says this vowel was usually low-mid in Middle English in the southern or A.S.-derived accents, while it was usually high-mid in Middle English in the Mercian or northern accents. Wikipedia also has a page that mentions this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_Old_English#Dialects

In many words, such as *seed, deed, greedy, needle,* modern spelling is based on the northern dialects rather than the southern. This also seems to be the case for the word *speech.*

#### Summary

According to Wiktionary, *speak* can be traced back to a PG verb **sprekaną* while *speech* can be traced back to a PG noun **sprēkijō.* In other words, they had different vowels. This is supported by evidence from other languages, like German *sprechen* "to speak" (with short /ɛ/) vs. *Sprache* "speech" (with long /aː/). I believe the vowel alternation in Proto-Germanic is due to the Proto-Indo-European process of ablaut, but that's just a guess.

The short vowel in the verb was lengthened in the Middle English period, a process which regularly resulted in low-mid long e which corresponds to the modern English spelling <ea>.

The long vowel in the noun developed differently in different dialects of Middle English. In the south, it was low-mid long e in Middle English. However, in the north, it developed to high-mid long e, which is the reason for the spelling with <ee> in Modern English.

#### Similar examples

A similar example of this kind of vowel alternation (but with different spelling) is the verb *bear* and the noun *bier* (which could be spelled *beer, bere, bear* in the past, according to the OED). The verb is from PG **ber-* and the noun is from *PG **bēr*-, as shown by the German cognate *Bahre.*